# How can i convert this JSON object into this format?

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs

I would to get some help on changing the data structure of a JSON object {Object - Object} into a format that works with Re-Charts data structure{Array - Object}. Can you please guide on how and what is the best way to solve for this. I really appreciate your time and let me know if I should provide any additional information.

> **JSON Object I would like to convert**

```
{
    "Date": {
      "0": "2019-08-02",
      "1": "2019-08-05",
      "2": "2019-08-06",
      "3": "2019-08-07",
      "4": "2019-08-08",
      "5": "2019-08-09",
      "6": "2019-08-12",
      "7": "2019-08-13",
      "8": "2019-08-14",
      "9": "2019-08-15",
      "10": "2019-08-16"
},
"Open": {
      "0": 205.529999,
      "1": 197.990005,
      "2": 196.309998,
      "3": 195.410004,
      "4": 200.199997,
      "5": 201.300003,
      "6": 199.619995,
      "7": 201.020004,
      "8": 203.160004,
      "9": 203.460007,
      "10": 204.279999
},
"High": {
      "0": 206.429993,
      "1": 198.649994,
      "2": 198.070007,
      "3": 199.559998,
      "4": 203.529999,
      "5": 202.759995,
      "6": 202.050003,
      "7": 212.139999,
      "8": 206.440002,
      "9": 205.139999,
      "10": 207.160004
}
}
```

> **Format I would like to convert to**

```
[{ Date: '2019-08-02', Open: 205.529999 }, { Date: '2019-08-05', Open: 197.990005}, { Date: '2019-08-06', Open: 196.309998}, {...} ]
```

Comment: Your question is unclear... where does 'Page A' uv etc come from?

Comment: Just edited the question, sorry for the unclarity!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I used to make it happen:

Initialized consts

```
const values = Object.values(Data.default)
const dates  = values[0]
const prices = values[1] 
const arr = [];
```

For Loop Statement (I had to work with the for loop to make this happen, please answer other ways that could be done without the for loop statement.)

```
var i; 
var l = Object.keys(dates).
for( i=0; i < l.length; i++ ) 
{
var b = {}; 
b["Dates"] = dates[i]
b["Prices"]= prices[i]
arr.push(b); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a map of the keys of the date option to iterate over these dates:

```
const arrData = Object.keys(data.Date).map((value, index) => {
    return {
      name: `Page ${String.fromCharCode(index+65)}`,
        uv: data.Open[index],
        pv: data.High[index]
    };
});
```

Or a reduce:

```
const arrData = Object.keys(data.Date).reduce((arr, value, index) => {
    arr.push({
      name: `Page ${String.fromCharCode(index+65)}`,
        uv: data.Open[index],
        pv: data.High[index],
        amt: 0 // Where ever you get this info from ;)
    })
    return arr;
}, []);
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't too clear in my question, I edited the question hopefully that will add more clarity to what i want to do.